# IntelliJ 14 not using specified JDK version?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently downloaded IntelliJ for Java programming, and while testing it out I realized it wasn't using  the right version of Java. I have this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String question = "0";
        switch (question){
            case"0":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it and it gave me this error in the console:

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_25 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Game'
Error:(9, 16) java: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

I went in `File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK` and saw that is was using 1.7.0, which should work, since using `Strings` in a switch was implemented in Java 7. I changed it to 1.8.0, and the problem is still there, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you have to tell Intellij which language level you would like as well.

Right under Project SDK is the option `Project Language Level`. Try changing that to 7 or 8.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that! Thanks very much :)